# a href links not clickable

Tags: html, css, z-index, href

I've a problem with a website I'm building.
I've a menu containing 2 links (called "Default" and "Test") into list items but in Firefox I can't click them.
In IE they works: I think is a z-index problem of items on the page but I can't solve it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.sezup li.current{
    color:#067d2c;
    position:relative;
    z-index:20;
}

.sezup a, a:hover{
    color:#067d2c;
    position:relative;
    z-index:20;
}
.header{
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
}
.sezup {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 0 0 75px;
    width:800px;
position:relative;
    z-index:20;
}
#lineaup {
    background: url("../Images/sfondobarraup.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 16px;
    margin: 55px 0 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    top: -25px;
    left: 0px;
}
#lineaup li {
    bottom: 6px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 2px 15px;
    position: relative;
}
.loghi {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px 0 0;
    position: relative;
    top: -45px;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 97px;
    border:1px black solid;
}
#logo {
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
    float:left;
}
#calciatore {
    position: relative;
    float:right;
    top:-50px;
}
#erba {
    background: url("../Images/erba.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 65px;
    position: relative;
    top: -110px;
    z-index: 0;
    border:1px black solid;
}
</style>
</head>
    <body>



        <div class="header">
            <div id="lineaup">
                <div class="sezup">
                    <ul>

                        <li class="current"><a href="Default.aspx" id="hrefHome">Default</a></li>
                        <li><a href="test.aspx?id=1" id="hrefProfile">Test</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="loghi">

                <img src="" title="logo" id="logo" /><img src="" title="logo" id="calciatore" />

            </div>

             <div id="erba">
             </div>
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Because of [the stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index/The_stacking_context), once you set a z-index on a parent element, you can't "break out" of it by setting a higher z-index on a child element.

Usually it's a lot easier to deal with by removing all the superfluous z-index values and only adding them where you need it.

[See demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/ePmyu/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of all `z-index` except for:

```
#lineaup {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

and

```
#erba {
    z-index: -1;
}
```

You should only change the `z-index` of the parent elements. There's no reason to assign the children elements with higher and higher `indices`.

Also, since it's usually just one element behind another, this `-1` and `1` solution not only works but looks nice, and is easy to understand, I think.

For the record, [negative z-indices are allowed](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Increase the z-index for #lineap

```
#lineaup {
  z-index: 1;
  ...
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/willemvb/wxWBm/